# Custom yang module usage (ConfD_basic 7.8.3)

Tags: ietf-netconf, netconf, yang, confd

I have written 3 function get_temperature(),get_ddr() and get_cpu_load() to calculate temperature,ddr usage and cpu load of an ubuntu system.These functions store the value into a structure.I have also written a custom YANG module system-monitoring.yang and compile it into a .fxs file and added it /etc/confd . I am using confd_basic_7.8.3. The confdc compiler was used for this to generate the .fxs file and a .h file. How can i use this custom YANG module and the confd API's to receive these values through the netconf-console command probably in an xml file.

Currently i have just written a main function which starts with confd_init(), and then confd_connect(). Can someone help me on writing the C application using the Confd api's for this?